# How to use WP_Term with (menu) argument in the wp_nav_menu?

Tags: plugin-development, functions, codex

I am trying to understand the `wp_nav_menu`function and i am okay with its arguments but wordpress states to use `int` , `string` and `WP_Term` with the `menu` key. I need to know how to use the `WP_Term` with it because wordpress just offers the core class `WP_Term`.You can just explain the concept if you want. Why and What the result of using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Background

As you already know, [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function takes an array `$args` as argument & `menu` is one of the keys to that `$args` array.

The key `menu` for the argument `$args` is defined as:

> (int|string|WP_Term) Desired menu. Accepts (matching in order) id, slug, name, menu object.

Now, if you look deep into the [implementation of `wp_nav_menu()` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L48), you'll see that, no matter what value you provide, whether it is an `int` *id*, a `string` *name*, a `string` *slug* or an `object` `WP_Term`, it'll always retrieve the `WP_Term` `object` for the corresponding menu *id* | *name* | *slug* before creating the menu.

For example: if you have a menu with *id* `3`, *name* `My Menu` and *slug* `my-menu`; you can add that menu using any of the following CODE:

```
    // with id: 3
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'           => 3
    ) );

    // with name: My Menu
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'           => "My Menu"
    ) );

    // with slug: my-menu
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'           => "my-menu"
    ) );
```

Even if you don't provide the `menu` argument, it'll try to get the `WP_Term` *object* from other arguments like `theme_location`.

For example: say the menu location `top` was registered using [`register_nav_menus()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menus/) function in your theme's `functions.php` file & the menu named `My Menu` was asigned to the `top` location from your *WP admin panel*. In that case, you can get the same menu using:

```
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'top'
    ) );
```

In each of the above cases, `wp_nav_menu()` function retrieves the `WP_Term` *object* before generating the menu. It uses the [`wp_get_nav_menu_object()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L18) function to do so.

## Implementation

So instead of `theme_location` argument, or `menu` argument as `int` *id* or `string` *name* | *slug*, you can directly provide the corresponding WP_Term object.

One way get the `WP_Term` object is by using the [`WP_Term::get_instance()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-wp-term.php#L109) method:

```
    // get the WP_Term object using menu id 3
    $menu_obj = WP_Term::get_instance( 3, 'nav_menu' );
```

You can also get the `WP_Term` object with menu *name* | *slug* using [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) function:

```
    // by menu slug
    $menu_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', 'my-menu', 'nav_menu' );

    // or, by menu name
    $menu_obj = get_term_by( 'name', 'My Menu', 'nav_menu' );
```

Now that you've got the `WP_Term` *object* `$menu_obj`, you can use that to generate the menu:

```
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'           => $menu_obj
    ) );
```

## Use case:

So you know how to generate a menu using `WP_Term` *object* as an argument to `wp_nav_menu()` function. Now the question is: *why will you want to use it?* Apart from the fact that **it's just another option**, you may want to use it because it may be a slightly faster option.

For example, if you want to use the same menu twice, once in the header & then in the footer, in that case, instead of using menu *id* | *slug* | *name*, you may create `WP_Term` object in your template for header menu:

```
    global $menu_obj;
    $menu_obj = WP_Term::get_instance( 3, 'nav_menu' );

    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'           => $menu_obj,
        'menu_id'        => 'header_menu'
    ) );
```

and then simply use `$menu_obj` in the footer template as well:

```
    // global declaration is needed to access the global variable from another template
    global $menu_obj;
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'           => $menu_obj,
        'menu_id'        => 'footer_menu'
    ) );
```

If you look into the implementation of `wp_nav_menu()` function, you'll see that by doing it this way, you will avoid a few extra function calls in WordPress core, thus the total execution will be slightly faster.

However, please remember that using `theme_location` argument or other options may be more convenient & better for maintenance. So whether or not you should use it totally depends on your own particular scenario. I just explained that you can & how, nothing more.

Comment: Wooooooooooow, I am amazed of this great answer... I really thank you for not only you have made me understand but also you took from your time to present this in detail answer, because i just realized that this is not easy question to answer.

Comment: I really appreciate you effort, thank you very much

Comment: I was going to answer in short, then I realized that others may benefit from it in the future as well. Thus the long answer. You are welcome.

Comment: You've done a great job here, and indeed it will be a benefit for many because no more details about this topic

Comment: This is very good!

maybe to mention that the filter 'wp_nav_menu_args' starts before the arguments are turned into a 'WP_Term' (nav-menu-template.php L71)

So checking against an ID or Name can be different when menus are created in the backend (WP_Term) or in a template(all possibilities).